# how to mpchart legend text Color change in android

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, legend, mpchart

When I googled the information, it said that I could use setCustom.

Only form, not label text is allowed in the entry in this section.

What I want is to make the legend's form color and label color the same. how to mpchart label text change?

legend.textColor can also only specify one color.

[image]

```
val entries: MutableList<LegendEntry> = ArrayList()
                                        for (i in 0 until strLegendList.size) {
                                            val entry = LegendEntry()
                                            entry.formColor = colorList[i]
                                            entry.label = strLegendList[i]

                                            entries.add(entry)
                                            legend.textColor = colorList[i]
                                            legend.setCustom(entries)
                                        }
```